# Java - Read and Write a .txt file

Tags: java, file, input, output

I want to read lines from a .txt file (in this case input.txt) and write them in two other .txt files depending on whether the integer number at the start of each line is odd or even. I have to use DataInputStream / DataOutputStream and BufferedInputStream / BufferedOutputStream.

The input file looks like this.

```js
1 String1 1.1
2 String2 2.2
3 String3 3.3
4 String4 4.4
5 String5 5.5
6 String6 6.6
7 String7 7.7
8 String8 8.8
9 String9 9.9
10 String10 10.1
```

When I run the program I get an EOFException, at the readUTF parts. When I comment those parts and try to write only the integers, I get only "1" in the odd file and "2" in the even file. It doesn't copy all the integers.

```js
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;

public class datastream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DataInputStream inputStream = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStreamEven = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStreamOdd = null;
         
        try {
            inputStream = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream ( new FileInputStream("src/input.txt")));
            outputStreamEven = new DataOutputStream (new BufferedOutputStream ( new FileOutputStream("src/even.txt")));
            outputStreamOdd = new DataOutputStream (new BufferedOutputStream ( new FileOutputStream("src/odd.txt")));

            int number;
            String textinput;
            double doublenumber;
            
            number = inputStream.readInt();
            textinput = inputStream.readUTF();
            doublenumber = inputStream.readDouble();
            
            while ((number = inputStream.read()) % 2 != 0) {
             outputStreamOdd.writeInt(number);
             outputStreamOdd.writeUTF(textinput);
                outputStreamOdd.writeDouble(doublenumber); 
            }
            
            while ((number = inputStream.read()) % 2 == 0) {
             outputStreamEven.writeInt(number);
             outputStreamEven.writeUTF(textinput);
             outputStreamEven.writeDouble(doublenumber);
            }
            
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (outputStreamEven != null) {
                outputStreamEven.close();
            }
            if (outputStreamOdd != null) {
                outputStreamOdd.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to copy all the lines to the appropriate text file (along with each line having all its contents)?

Comment: DataInputStream and DataOutputStream don't do what you think they do.

Comment: As immibis said it is probably not doing what you expecting. Why don't you use `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`? They are much more simpler. `BufferedReader fd  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));`, read like `fd.readLine()` and then split all those values. BTW, you should be catching the exception and stop read/write from/to the file.

Comment: What part of `EOFException` don't you understand? You got to the end of the file: you should stop reading it. But if it's a text file, you shouldn't be usig `readUTF()` on it. The `readUTF()` method only understands data written by `writeUTF()`. If it's lines, you should use `BufferedReader.readLine().` Whoever said you have to use `DataInput/OutputStream` to read or write text files is wrong.

Comment: I don't think you need a `BufferedInputStream` on top of a `FileInputStream`. Shouldn't your `DataInputStream` be declared using only the `FileInputStream`? Such as `inputStream = new DataInputStream (new FileInputStream("src/input.txt"));`, and same goes for the `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: @BinaryJudy You almost always need a `BufferedReader` on top of any other `Reader` except another `BufferedReader`. In this case the OP needs to read lines, which `FileReader` doesn't support and `BufferedReader` does.

Comment: @EJP Okay, thanks. Also, it looks like op is required to use "DataInputStream / DataOutputStream and BufferedInputStream / BufferedOutputStream".

Comment: @BinaryJudy Exactly. We are required to use DataInputStream, BufferedInputStream, DataOutputStream και BufferedOutputStream for inputs and outputs respectively. I've tried using `BufferedReader` in order to copy the full line each time an paste it using  `DataOutpustStream` but I still have a problem with reading the first number of each line with `DataInputStream`. That part of the code is this.

`while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null){  
             if ((number = inputStream.read()) % 2 != 0){  
              outputStreamOdd.writeUTF(thisLine);  
             }  
         else...  
}`

Comment: @vic Did you figure it out? This "`while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null)...`" doesn't match what you have posted in the question. Specifically the while with the "`br`". Please post what you have updated in the code, especially if it's gotten you closer to the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are manipulating a text file, therefore you should rather use characters streams to handle this.

So using BufferedReader and BufferedWriter would help you solve this issue in a simple way. Here is a code that does that. I have copied your sample datas in a text file and called it sourceData.txt

```
public class OddEvenFileManager {

    public static final String DATA_SOURCE_PATH = "sourceDatas.txt";
    public static final String ODD_TARGET_PATH =  "oddDatas.txt";
    public static final String EVEN_TARGET_PATH = "evenDatas.txt";


    public static void doOddEvenSplitting() throws IOException,     NumberFormatException {

        BufferedReader sourceReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new     File(DATA_SOURCE_PATH)));
        BufferedWriter oddWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new     File(ODD_TARGET_PATH)));
        BufferedWriter evenWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new     File(EVEN_TARGET_PATH)));

        String sourceLine = null;

        while ((sourceLine = sourceReader.readLine()) != null) {
            int lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(sourceLine.split(" ")[0]);

            if (lineNumber % 2 == 0) {
                evenWriter.write(sourceLine);
                evenWriter.newLine();

            } else {
                oddWriter.write(sourceLine);
                oddWriter.newLine();
            }

        }

        sourceReader.close();
        oddWriter.close();
        evenWriter.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,     NumberFormatException {
        doOddEvenSplitting();
    }
}
```